# Issue while updating huge xlsx file

Tags: xlsx

our requirement is that user will upload a xlsx file and we have to validate the file for data type for each cell value if there is any error(mismatch of data type) then we have to write into the xls with an additional column as remarks with error details and return back to user.

So for that I am reading the xlsx file first and retrieving the data type of cell for first row using Apache POI(Java API) and then verifying each row and each cell based on the data type(from first row) and this mechanism is working fine for file having up to 20K to 30K records but when I am processing large xlsx file having 100K records it is not able to process. I am having heap space issue.

I am using Apache POI(Java API) for iteration and Excel version is 32-bit.

When searched for any solution I am getting solution for how to read or write huge xls file. but as I have to get the cell data type and then update same xlsx if any error is there I could not able to get any solution for this kind of case.

Please let me know if anyone having any solution for this kind of issue.

Please find the below code which I am using :

```
                Set set = remarksInfo.entrySet(); //HashMap object
                Integer rownumber;
                String value;
                Iterator iterator = set.iterator();
                //Read Excel document first
                FileInputStream input_document = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\simple.xlsx"));                                      
                XSSFWorkbook my_xlsx_workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(input_document);

                XSSFSheet my_worksheet = my_xlsx_workbook.getSheetAt(0);                                        
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry mentry = (Map.Entry) iterator.next();
                rownumber = (Integer) mentry.getKey();
                value = (String) mentry.getValue();
                Row row = mySheet.getRow(rownumber);
                Cell newCell = row.createCell(mySheet.getRow(rownumber).getLastCellNum() - 2);
                newCell.setCellValue(value);
                newCell.setCellStyle(style);
                }
                input_document.close();
                FileOutputStream output_file =new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\simple.xlsx"));
                my_xlsx_workbook.write(output_file);
                //close the stream
                output_file.close();
```

ERROR :

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded] with root cause
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellReference.separateRefParts(CellReference.java:361)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellReference.<init>(CellReference.java:92)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.<init>(XSSFCell.java:106)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow.<init>(XSSFRow.java:69)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.initRows(XSSFSheet.java:234)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.read(XSSFSheet.java:197)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.onDocumentRead(XSSFSheet.java:184)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.onDocumentRead(XSSFWorkbook.java:350)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:166)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:259)
    at pxs.dgd.gna.fileUpload.FileUploadXls.getXcelSheetinfoMap(FileUploadXls.java:101)
    at pxs.dgd.gna.services.GNAServiceImple.getXcelSheetinfoMap(GNAServiceImple.java:225)
    at pxs.dgd.gna.controller.FileUploadController.getSheetDetails(FileUploadController.java:203)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:111)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:806)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:729)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
```

Comment: First: What is your method of iterating through the data?  Are you using `c#`?  `PowerShell`?  Any sort of scripting?  That would be useful, and generally requested in [ask].  Second: Are you using 32-bit or 64-bit versions of Excel/Office?  Please [edit] your question and include those details.

Comment: I am using Apache POI(Java API) for iteration and Excel version is 32-bit.

Comment: You'll need to show what code you're running, and the exact specific errors, for any practical advice on why you may be running into heap space errors.  I have a theory (having encountered issues similar to this), but would need to see how you're allocating the data and handling disposal before moving on.

Comment: I have added the code and the error details above.

Comment: Could you help with the solution for the above issue